# Using a special calculator to write to a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a downloaded Excel spreadsheet that has a special built-in calculator.

In another sheet I have my list of 173 values. These I enter into the calculator cell, press enter in another cell and in another cell the return value pops up.

I want the value of each return cell to be entered adjacent to its list value.

How can I do this without using an `IF` statement?

Comment: How is the return value generated? Does it have a formula in the cell, or is it the result of a macro?

Comment: it calcultes it using an imported program. A macro i guess

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular feature in Excel for doing exactly this sort of thing: a *Data Table*.

You nominate an existing output cell and 1 or 2 input cells from anywhere in the same worksheet (parts of your 'special calculator'), and a range containing the inputs you want to use (in this case, your 173 values). You then get a 1-way or 2-way table containing the values that the output cell would have taken for each of a range of values of the input cells. The intermediate calculation can be as complex as you like and can reference cells on other worksheets.

What you would need to do if you wanted to change more than two inputs at a time is start by listing every combination you want to use as scenarios in a table:

```
scenario    var1    var2    var3
1   1   1   2
2   1   3   2
3   2   1   1
```

Then you can use vlookups based on a cell containing the scenario number to populate all the other cells you want to change, and set the scenario cell as the row input to a 1-way data table.